# Comparing Growth Curve P-Values, Different Length Data Sets

Tags: calculus, statistics

I have two growth curve data sets, A (Martians) and B (Venusians). Data point sets of age (0 (birth) - 250 months, X axis) against height (0 - 200 centimeters, Y axis). The first set (A) contains 67 X Y point pairs, the second set (B) contains 27 point pairs. I have fit both data sets to my favorite version of the Logistic Equation using NonlinearModelFit. NonlinearModelFit returns estimates for my two independent variables: Increment, (N0), and Time Coefficient (k). Then following I invoked "ParameterTable" calculating: (1) Standard Errors (2) t-Statistics and (3) P-Values for both of the curve fitting exercises, Martians and Venusians. Of the three Parameters: Standard Errors, t-Statistics, and P-Values, which parameter indicates a better fit to an energy conservative logistic equilibrium? Standard Errors on the calculated Time Coefficients (k)? t-Statistics on the calcuated Time Coefficents (k)? Is growth on Mars more of an energy conservative mechanical process than growth on Venus? Are data sets with different numbers of point pairs directly comparable on Standard Errors, t-Statistics and P-Values?

Comment: For whatever it's worth, this exact question has been asked under two other usernames in the last day or so and put on hold at both https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/162772/problem-with-nonlinearmodelfit-parametertable#comment431552_162772  and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/320862/comparing-p-values-data-sets-with-different-numbers-of-point-pairs#comment609139_320862.

Comment: You people are not understanding my question.

Comment: I think we are understanding the question.  You want to compare the fits (either predictions, estimates of parameters, etc.) between the two data sets.  That's a reasonable thing to do.  You just don't do that by comparing P-values which is what your text indicates.  So clarifying what you want to do (as opposed to how to do it) would likely get your question re-opened on the other forums.

Comment: You've not provided a **research hypothesis**.  You do not explain what the data represent, nor do you explain the intended goal of your analysis.  What you have provided so far--comparison of p-values--reflects a fundamental lack of understanding of statistics.  Just because you fit a model to you data and get some p-values, does not mean you understand what you are doing.  It is for this reason that your posts have been closed as being unclear. Simply shopping around for answers will not change the fact that the question makes no sense and provides insufficient detail for others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Two different data sets are not comparable. You can only use one data set as a training set and the other one as a test set. But then the comparison is not much of a comparison rather a test whether the model that you've fitted to the first set is also valid for the second one.

Answer (score 0):

In short you have a basic misunderstanding as to what a P-value is.  A P-value 
for one of the regression coefficients is the probability of obtaining an estimate
at least as extreme as the one observed given that the true regression coefficient
is zero.  It is not the probability that the true regression coefficient is zero (which
is one of the reasons why it is inappropriate to compare P-values to test for equality).

Also, if the underlying coefficients are not zero and very similar, then the data set with
the larger sample size will tend to have smaller P-values.  (Another reason why it is
inappropriate to compare P-values to test for equality.)

So the answers to the three questions are (1) No, (2) No, and (3) No.

If you want to compare regression coefficients between two different data sets,
then (in general) you would get the estimates (say, $\hat{c}_A$ and $\hat{c}_B$) and
the estimates of the standard errors (say, $\hat{\sigma}_A$ and $\hat{\sigma}_B$).
Then calculate

$$z= {{{\hat{c}_A} - {\hat{c}_B}} \over \sqrt{\hat{\sigma}^2_A + \hat{\sigma}^2_B}} $$

If $|z|>1.96$, then you reject the hypothesis of equal coefficients at the 5% level.  (And this
assumes that you want to test a hypothesis rather than estimate a difference or ratio of
regression coefficients.)

Editing your question (or opening a new one) to reflect the subject matter questions you want answered will get you more targeted advice.